# CGAL - Preserve attributes on vertex using corefine boolean operations

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal

I'm relatively new to CGAL, so please pardon me if there is an obvious fix to this that I'm missing.

I was following this example on preserving attributes on facets of a polyhedral mesh after a corefine+boolean operation:

https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Polygon_mesh_processing/examples/Polygon_mesh_processing/corefinement_mesh_union_with_attributes.cpp

I wanted to know if it was possible to construct a Visitor struct which similarly operates on vertices of a polyhedral mesh. Ideally, I'd like to interpolate property values (a vector of doubles) from the original mesh onto the new boolean output vertices, but I can settle for imputing nearest neighbor values.

The difficulty I was running into was that the after_subface_created and after_face_copy functions overloaded within Visitor operate before the halfedge structure is set for the target face and hence, I'm not sure how to access the vertices of the target face. Is there a way to use the Visitor structure within corefinement to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

In an older version of the code I used to have a visitor handling vertex creation/copy but it has not been backported (due to lack of time). What you are trying to do is a good workaround but you should use the visitor to collect the information (say fill a map `[input face] -> std::vector<output face>`) and process that map once the algorithm is done.